# Standard input as a plain-text

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

how to give standard input --stdin by using **<** symbol,as a plain text(string) in bash script, 
For example i have stored /etc/passwd file by using redirecting **>** symbol by the same way i want to give plain text as a input

Comment: Apart from using `<`, are you concerned about _plain text_ in any particular way? Your question mentions _plain text_ three times.

Answer (score 3):

To redirect from stdin, you don't use `<` you use `|`. For example (apologies for the useless use of cat)

```
cat /some/file | my_program
```

If your "stored /etc/passwd file" resides in a variable, and you are not tied to /bin/sh, you can use the `<<<` redirection

```
my_program <<< "$my_variable"
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you describe, with the indirection (`<`) operator:

```
/path/to/executable < /path/to/inputfile
```